Is there a similar library, or a work-around for the lib "PyWin32" for a school owned Google chrome book?
I am writing a clicker game for part of my final project, and need to use win32api as it lets me track button clicks.
I have been able to install Pypiwin32, but I don't know if, or how it works. Whenever I run the file, it tells me "No module name 'win32api'". Is there a workaround? Does Pypiwin32 have a similar way to do this? Do I have to restart?
(P.S. The reason why I am using win32api instead of something native to chrome os is because I have been mainly developing this project using my home PC, and the computer lab PCs; all of which use windows 10-11 os.)
Any help?

pip install pywin32, not pypiwin32.  That project has similar maintainers, but are for older versions and might even be release mistakes.  PyWin32 306 is the latest version.

Should have clarified this in the original post - whenever I pip install pywin32, it runs an error stating that there is no version able to satisfy. I must add that I am using cs50.dev for my coding environment as VS Code cannot be installed onto google OS.

You can [edit] your post with clarifying information, but pywin32 is only for the Windows OS.
